# PL/pgSQL : Does DISTINCT ON passes through with it's result onto next CTE?

Tags: postgresql, distinct, plpgsql, common-table-expression, distinct-on

My code looks like this (schema), because it's pretty huge:

```
something AS ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (x1,x2,x3,x4) ... ),
something2 AS (xx.*, ... FROM something xx LEFT JOIN ...),
something3 AS (xx.*, ... FROM something2 xx LEFT JOIN ...)
SELECT ... FROM something3
```

So imagine this situation:
After using **DISTINCT ON (x1,x2,x3,x4)** in `something` and then

```
select * from something
```

(ignoring `something2 and something3` here) : **I get 1700 results.**

But **the problem is** this is not my expected result (yet), because I need to use some more CTE to leftjoin some information

So when I have the same **DISTINCT ON** in `something` and I do

`select * from something3` (which is a final expected result that should return 1700 rows)

I suddenly get 4000 results with the values that I wanted to distinct earlier on in `something`.

It seems like I'm losing the `DISTINCT` I've typed in `something`, because when I put the same syntax:

`DISTINCT ON (x1,x2,x3,x4) ...` in all three `something's` then I get 1700 results - But it's not really what I'm looking for.

*Time means much to me.*

Could someone help me out with the solution and better understanding of the problem here?

Comment: Just a quick comment, ime doesn't seem to be any different (explain seems to lower just a little bit) if let's say distinct on in `something2 and something3` are not used.

I hope that you realize what I'm trying to get. DISTINCT the result in first CTE, and then use the DISTINCT resultset in other CTEs and then get a result out of it

Comment: I don't think you've read the whole question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, [because](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

> CTEs can be thought of as defining temporary tables that exist just for one query.

Which means, that doesn't matter, if you defined one of your CTE with a `DISTINT ON` clause, because other CTEs (and your main query) will see only a temporary table (or more like a result-set), but nothing more. If use use join on this temporary table, [you could end up more results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2408) (just like with normal tables).

To ensure your main query does not contain duplicates, move the `DISTINT ON` clause there (or, in theory, all of your CTEs can have it - but at least the last one should have).

F.ex. these should produce your desired output:

```
WITH s AS (SELECT x FROM t),
s2 AS (SELECT x FROM s),
s3 AS (SELECT x FROM s2),
SELECT DISTINCT x FROM s3;

-- vs.

WITH s AS (SELECT x FROM t),
s2 AS (SELECT x FROM s),
s3 AS (SELECT DISTINCT x FROM s2),
SELECT x FROM s3;

-- vs.

WITH s AS (SELECT DISTINCT x FROM t),
s2 AS (SELECT DISTINCT x FROM s),
s3 AS (SELECT DISTINCT x FROM s2),
SELECT x FROM s3;

-- this last version should be only used, when you have
-- enormous joins, so you want to keep your "temporary"
-- tables' size smaller in the memory
```

Comment: That's the answer I've been looking for. Just needed a confirmation that it doesn't pass on with the distinct values. Thanks a lot, in my case that would be huge amount of data in joining tables, which is why I wanted to distinct at first.